# TLS on Elastic Beanstalk running reverse proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I want to add TLS to my AWS Elastic Beanstalk application. It is a node.js app running behind nginx proxy server.

Here are the steps I've completed

1. Get a wildcard certificate from Amazon Certificate Manager.
2. Add the certificate in the load balancer configuration section of my EB instance.

[image]

My relevant part of my nginx config is

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
  mode: "000644"
  content: |
    upstream nodejs {
      server 127.0.0.1:8081;
      keepalive 256;
    }

    server {
      listen 8080;

      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      if ( $http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https' ) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      }

      location / {
        proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      }
    }
```

When I try to access my application using https, I get a `408: Request Timed Out`.

It is my understanding that to enable ssl on nginx we need to add the cert along with pem file and listen on port 443. But since I'm using ACM certificate, I don't have the cert and pem files.

What am I missing to add in my nginx.conf for this to work?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to install the SSL certificate on Nginx since the load balancer is performing SSL termination.  The first thing you should check is that port 443 is open in the Security Group assigned to the load balancer.

Comment: @MarkB The security group assigned to the load has an inbound rule listening on 443.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the load balancer listener configuration, for the port `443` listener, the "Instance Port" setting should be `80`.